# Node.js pm2 is not working in the jenkins pipeline

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pm2, jenkins-groovy

I have used pm2 for node.js application to build with help of jenkins pipeline. For my application to start, it needs the another application to running on the particular port. For achieving this with CI on jenkins I used pm2 to run the process in background so it can go for next stage.

In my local machine pm2 is running successfully .But in jenkins it is not starting the application, and also it does not shows any error message, but I am sure the application was not running with pm2. What may be a reason.

Any Help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
pm2 startup
```

And execute the suggested command.

If you are using NVM and you execute a shell script with Jenkins, add this at the beginning.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```

Comment: Thanks. In my jenkins pipeline script I wrote a code like sh 'npm install' and sh 'pm2 start server.js' so where I want to add the above scripts in jenkins pipeline..

Comment: I am running my jenkins in a separate ubuntu server.

Comment: Josean I am in need of your help. Please clarify my doubts.

Comment: In your ubuntu server enter pm2 startup and execute the suggested command. In your jenkins script paste the export NVM... that works for me.